# unable to get value of variable while debugging

Tags: debugging, ironpython, pdb

I run my script from the command line as follows:

```
ipy -X:FullFrames myscript.py
```

There are lines in my code which invoke the debugger. So there is a `pdb.set_trace()` somewhere in there.

The debugging happens however, its not at the position I have called `set_trace`; it happens few lines afterward. I can't say how further since it varies by 3-4 lines. (Weird behavior).

So I continue debugging. I step in a method, and try to inspect a variable value: So I type in this at the below prompt:

```
(Pdb) p lst
```

It gives me an ouput:

```
<cell at 45: list object at 46>
```

I am not getting variable value. How to understand what that means?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I found running IronPython with `-X:Frames` rather than `-X:FullFrames` solved it for me.